# Cant connect to local MySQL “only” when connected to VPN on VM?

Tags: virtual-machine, vpn, mysql, vmware-fusion, split-tunnel

Setup:

- MySQL installed on my Mac using Xammp
- Virtual Machine installed using VMware Fusion running Windows XP.

I am able to connect to the MySQL database (192.168.0.11) through my VM normally.

As soon as I connect to a VPN it stops connecting to the MySQL.

Please let me know how can I make it work so that it connects to MySQL no matter if VPN is ON or OFF.

Here I am adding the Ipconfig of the changes: first part is Ipconfig without VPN and second is with.

[image]

Comment: Your VPN client is most likely receiving a default route option from the server or its config. You need to override this route in your routing table using "route add" command.

Comment: Hi @Linef4ult - I am not able to figure out how do I add route. The VPN I am using is HMA.

Comment: Same issue here, not answered: https://forum.hidemyass.com/index.php/topic/11968-default-gateway/

Comment: Looks like in Dashboard-Settings you may have the ability to configure it correctly. If you use the pro service. If its the free service I'm not sure its possible.

Comment: I have the pro service. I just added an image with the Ipconfig details with and without vpn.

Comment: its "route print" thats more important than ipconfig.

Comment: The client itself should allow you to make exceptions though that'll be more user friendly.

Answer (score 0):

Using 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost as my host in the mysql connection settings solved the issue for me. 
I am on Avaya VPN